# Concat a collection's sub arrays and merge their parent

Tags: javascript, lodash.js

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = [
    {
        revision: 19,
        text: 'hello',
        details: [
            {
                id: 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        revision: 19,
        text: 'hello',
        details: [
            {
                id: 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        revision: 17,
        text: 'world',
        details: [
            {
                id: 7
            }    
        ]
    }
];
```

And I'd like to concat its details arrays if the revision is the same (the `text` values are the same if they got the same `revision` value):

```
var expected = [
    {
        revision: 19,
        text: 'hello',
        details: [
            {
                id: 5
            },
            {
                id: 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        revision: 17,
        text: 'world',
        details: [
            {
                id: 7
            }    
        ]
    }
];
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
constructArray(groupByRevisionNb(arr));

function groupByRevisionNb(arr) {
    return _.groupBy(arr, 'revision');
}

function constructArray(obj) {
    return _.map(obj, function (arr) {
        return concatRevisions(arr);
    });
}

function concatRevisions(arr) {
    return _.reduce(arr, function (obj1, obj2) {
        if (_.isEmpty(obj1)) {
            obj1 = _.clone(obj2);
        } else {
            obj1.details = obj1.details.concat(obj2.details);
        }
        return obj1;
    }, {});
}
```

But I'm not 100% satisfied with it. What could be improved?

I'm not using ES6.

Comment: Try it out here https://glot.io/snippets/ee5bgy3ejx

Comment: What happens to `text` when merging?

Comment: The `text` values are the same if they got the same `revision` value

Comment: That may need to be mentioned in the post.

Comment: You're right, I add that

Comment: Am I missing something? http://i.imgur.com/aFCo6Zi.png And here's a pen: http://codepen.io/pen?editors=0012

Comment: Shouldn't your comment be an answer? :) (the codepen link is broken)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done natively:

```
var revisionMap = arr.reduce((map, entry) => {
  var revision = entry.revision;

  if(map.hasOwnProperty(revision))
    map[revision].details.push(...entry.details);
  else
    map[revision] = _.clone(entry);

  return map;
}, {});

/*
{
  1: { revision: REV, text: TEXT, details: [] },
  2: { revision: REV, text: TEXT, details: [] },
}
*/

var expected = Object.keys(revisionMap).map( key => revisionMap[key] );

/*
[
  { revision: REV, text: TEXT, details: [] },
  { revision: REV, text: TEXT, details: [] },
]
*/
```

First, make a mapping of ID to revision data. This way, we can easily check the existence of an already visited revision and know when to append rather than assign. Then, we convert that object into an array.

The only thing not native is the use of `_.clone` as we don't want to be modifying the original data when we're be appending details.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am not using ES6 (added to the question by now) but it's probably easily portable. Your code is really pretty though.